# How can we replace space in url with dash?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs and working on a small project, What I want is to replace white space with dash(-) in url parameters. Anybody help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Huh?  I know you are not asking where the dash is on your keyboard, but that would answer what you've asked.

Comment: what do you want to say? please explain bit more. @zipzit

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna to replace whitespace with dash then use following regex `let

```
let myString = "Stack Over Flow";
myString = myString.replace(/\s+/g, '-');

console.log(myString);`// Stack-Over-Flow
```

Comment: How to replace in URL?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using react-router for routing then you can replace the URL like:

```
let Url = props.history.location.pathname.replace(/ /g, '-');
```

By doing this, if your URL is 
   "/questions/50443435/how can we replace space in url with dash"

Then the result will be

"/questions/50443435/how-can-we-replace-space-in-url-with-dash"

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`string#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with regular expression.

```
let str = "repace  space me with dash"

str.replace(/ /g,'-'); // g - replace all
```

Comment: how to implement in reactjs ?

Comment: You can use it as it is in React.There is no react synax.We use JAVASCRIPT only in React

Comment: ohh so we can use Javascript in react component?

Comment: i am using decodeURI(str) but there is not change in url.

Comment: Could you please add that script as well in

Answer (score 1):

Just add .replace(/ /g, "-") after the link parameters.

`<Link to={`/article/${article.title.replace(/ /g, "-")}`}>Link </Link>`

`<a href={`/article/${article.title.replace(/ /g, "-")}`}>Link </a>`

Comment: also you can add .toLowerCase() after the replace to have them all in lower case

Comment: the question needs tags.